# Find out the default record type of any Object in Apex

Tags: apex, sobject, record-type, profile

I've to find out the default record type of an Object so that I can use in Apex to insert/update records.

Found out that it is at the user level(`user profile` based). Is there any other way which I can use to find out the default record type of an object.

It makes sense why it is at the user level, but just out of curiosity I'm looking for another option to get irrespective of the user profile.

Comment: I'm wondering about your need to know the default record type. When apex code executes as a user, the sobject record that will be created will have the record type which is default for the users profile for that sObject.

Comment: That is correct! I over thought the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Happens all the time ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use apex describe to get the record type details of any object. This information will be correct for the running user.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Schema.RecordTypeInfo defaultRecordType;
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rti : dsr.getRecordTypeInfos()) {
    if(rti.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()) {
        defaultRecordType = rti;
    }
}
```

Comment: As techtrekker said, that was unnecessary. But on the other hand, the snippet worked as expected! Thanks!